# verification links and rules governing nonce creation

Tags: php, cryptography

My intent is that when a user updates its email a verification email is sent where a verification link is contained in them and the user just has to click this link to verify the email update.It is standard practice in the web.

The verification link will contain a nonce which will be cross checked with one in the db and if both are same this will mean that the verification will have taken place.

My question has to do with the creation of the nonce and what function I must use to create it.
This a nonce where security is not a top priority-we are not dealing with passwords here.
PHP function uniqid() seems a good option but I wanted to here some opinions about the matter.
What function do you use to create a nonce for the email verification links.

I cannot reach a decision about the matter because maybe I am not aware of all the factors that come into play and which factors must determine the decision to be taken

Comment: If its not very security-critical a SHA-1/2 output with `uniqid()` is good enough. Make sure the link expires after some period of time (e.g 24-hours) to prevent brute-force attacks. If the application is more security-critical, perhaps include a security question that needs answering. A temporal hash which exists for only a short amount of time is generally secure-enough by modern standards.

Comment: I have not found any SHA1/2 algorithm(unless you meant SHA2 which I did not found either), only SHA1. Ok I taken care the algorithm thing.How I could make it expire after 24h...I do not expect you write the whole code required...I just need some guidance though,thanks.

Comment: I meant `SHA-1` or `SHA-2` (where SHA-2 is more commonly referred to as `SHA-512` OR `SHA-256`. I assume you are storing your temporary links in a database? In that case, most database engines come with a task scheduler in which you can periodically execute SQL statements. All you need to do is something like `DELETE * FROM dbname WHERE (now() - timestamp) > 86400` (In the SQL statement). And have it execute every hour or so.

Comment: I finally used SHA1.In the database I store only the nonce, not the whole link...as for the task scheduler, I hear about it for the first time,I will look into it.Thanks